# My Javascript code not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a simple function that increment number and bind with multiple Table as **S.NO.**. I don't understand what's wrong with my code.

```
    function _IncrementNumber(id) {
        var table = document.getElementById(id);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
            table.rows[i + 1].cells[0].innerHTML = (i + 1);
        }
    }
$(document).ready(function () {
    _IncrementNumber("FirstTable");
    _IncrementNumber("SecondTable");
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/anJyR/8/)**
Please guide me.

Comment: you start with table.rows[1], thus skipping table.rows[0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access a row that doesnt exist.

You should start with i=1 instead to skip the header row

```
for (var i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {
    table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML = (i);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are accessing **i+1** instead of **i**.
In the last iteration -> you will go out of bounds.

```
function _IncrementNumber(id) {
        var table = document.getElementById(id);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
            table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML = (i + 1);
        }
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    _IncrementNumber("FirstTable");
    _IncrementNumber("SecondTable");
});
```

Comment: i start incremented value after table heading so i think i have to use **rowCount-1** and **rows[i+1]**

Answer (score 0):

the error at this line was the issue. Table rows starts from 0 index. so dont need to increment the rows index change to this `table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML = (i + 1);`